# Inside Axios State Is Not Updating for React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

In this example setAuth state is not updating inside axios call. I tried to update the state after API call if HTTP status code is 200. But state is not updating.

```
export default function SignIn() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    //var apiBaseUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/login";
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

    var payload = {
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    }
}
    const handleClick = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(payload);
        // console.log(event);

        axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/login', payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.status);

                if (response.status === 200)
                    setAuth(true);
                    console.log(auth);

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: QQ - Would you try putting the `console.log(auth)` at the top of the function body? Additionally - avoid the single line conditional & use the full `if(){...}`

Comment: Also also - welcome to SO, enjoy your first updoot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more what you're trying to achieve

```
export default function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  //var apiBaseUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/login";
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  var payload = {
      "email": email,
      "password": password
  }

  console.log(auth);

  const handleClick = (event) => { // IN THE CLOSURE! :)

    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(payload);

    axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/login', payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);

            if (response.status === 200)
                setAuth(true);

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }

  return <div>{auth}</div> // Just returning JSX to get the point across.
}
```

1. Those hooks are tricky and all 'their concerns' need to be in the function body
2. The conditional you setup had a syntax issue
3. The position of the `console.log(auth)` shouldnt be in the callback to reflect the state you're looking for.